# Bash "file --mime-type" command is not working in Perl Script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, command

I am trying to run bash commands inside Perl script. I am using `system("file --mime-type $fileName);` but it is not working while other commands are working such as `ls or pwd`.
In the terminal, it says "Cannot open 'Paper(filename)' (No such file or directory).
Below is my code:-

```
foreach my $a(@ARGV)
    {
        opendir(DIR, $a) or die "You've Passed Invalid Directory as Arguments or $!\n";

        while(my $fileName = readdir DIR)
        {
            next if $fileName =~ /^\./; #this is to remove dotted hidden files.

            system("file --mime-type $fileName");

            print $fileName,"\n";
        }

        closedir(DIR);
    }
```

Please see the screenshot of error message in terminal:

[image: Error Message: Cannot Open 'Paper' file.]

I am wondering why is this not working like other commands? When I type this command solely in terminal then it shows the file type correctly but not in the Perl script.
Some help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$filename` is just the filename, it doesn't include the directory portion. So `file` is looking for the file in your working directory, not the directory in `$a`.

You need to concatenate the directory name and filename to get a full pathname. Also, you should give a list of arguments to `system()`, since you're not using shell parsing.

```
system('file',  '--mime-type', "$a/$fileName");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit. Could you please also tell me how to use it with Backticks? I may need to store it in a scalar. Furthermore, why we are required to use '$a'? Thanks!

Comment: I explained why we need to use `$a`. How else do you expect `file` to know what directory the file is in?

Comment: See https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch19_06.htm for how to translate backticks to safe code that doesn't use shell parsing.